# How to handle external auth redirect in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am working on an application where I am hitting a service and getting the response. Now, the service has auth configured which redirects to a login form if user is not authenticated. This auth redirection works on browser and user is able to login. However, I am trying to make a nodejs server that will internally hit the service. But the issue is that I am getting the login form html in response because user is not logged in.

So, how do I use that html response in nodejs endpoint, then complete the authentication and then send the real service response back to the user?

Requirement flow -

1. I am making a nodejs endpoint `/api-working`
2. User hits the `/api-working` endpoint
3. Inside the above endpoint, I am calling another service `/some-service`
4. `/some-service` redirects to `/auth` when user is unauthenticated
5. When I hit 'some-service' inside `/api-working`, it returns login form html as response (as user is not authentication)
6. Now, how to further return this html from `/api-working` endpoint so that user can complete the authentication?

Is there a better way to do this?